# Error: BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Overloads Function Copy(str As String) As String'

Tags: vb.net

```
`Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCopyFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Display a folder browser dialog to select the source folder to copy
        Dim folderBrowserDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog()
        If folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' Set the source folder path
            Dim sourceFolder As String = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

            ' Set the destination folder path
            Dim destinationFolder As String = "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\curseforge\minecraft\Instances"

            ' Copy the folder recursively
            CopyFolder(sourceFolder, destinationFolder)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyFolder(ByVal sourceFolder As String, ByVal destinationFolder As String)
        ' Get the subdirectories of the source folder
        Dim subDirectories As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder)

        ' Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
        If Not Directory.Exists(destinationFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder)
        End If

        ' Copy each file in the source folder to the destination folder
        For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder)
            ' Get the destination file path
            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
            Dim destinationFile As String = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName)

            ' Copy the file
            file.Copy(file, destinationFile)

            ' Update the progress bar
            UpdateProgressBar()
        Next

        ' Recursively copy each subdirectory in the source folder to the destination folder
        For Each subDirectory As String In subDirectories
            ' Get the destination subdirectory path
            Dim subDirectoryName As String = Path.GetFileName(subDirectory)
            Dim destinationSubDirectory As String = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, subDirectoryName)

            ' Recursively copy the subdirectory
            CopyFolder(subDirectory, destinationSubDirectory)
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub UpdateProgressBar()
        ' Increase the progress bar value by one
        progressBar1.Value += 1

        ' Refresh the progress bar
        progressBar1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
`
```

Error on line 36 on file.Copy(file, destinationFile)

Comment: There's no need to check if a directory exists before calling `Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder)` - it isn't an error if it does.

Comment: Instead of using `"C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName`, it is likely to be more reliable to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`. And [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) is made to build paths.

Answer (score 4):

`file` is the variable defined in your For Each loop and is not the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) class you are expecting. Your current code is using the [String.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy) method which only accepts one argument (hence the error you are getting) and isn't the method you are thinking it is.

To use the File class, you will have to properly qualify the method name:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(file, destinationFile)
```

You could also use [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copyfile) to copy `file` to `destinationFile`:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(file, destinationFile)
```

Comment: Or use a different name for the variable.

Comment: I would second the motion to use a different variable name. Given that the variable named `file` actually contains the path of a file, I would name it `filePath`.